# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'library.lib'

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, static-libraries

My original source code is a more complex, but I reduced it to one **header.hxx** and one **impl.cxx** file, because It's a question about MS Visual Studio **link.exe**.

I wrote a batch for a static library building. Here are the commands I used:

```
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 10.0.22621.0
```

```
cl /c /EHsc /nologo /W3 /D "_DEBUG" impl.cxx
```

```
link /OUT:"library.lib" /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /NOLOGO /MACHINE:X64 impl.obj
```

The compilation works fine, but the linker shows this error:

```
Creating library library.lib and object library.exp
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'library.lib'
```

What is wrong/missing in my commandline calls?

Here is the source code:

**header.hxx**

```
#pragma once

extern __declspec(dllexport) int abc1();
```

**impl.cxx**

```
#include "header.hxx"

extern __declspec(dllexport) int abc1()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cannot open file 'library.lib'` usually because either the file is already in use by some program, or you don't have permission to write to the output directory (whatever that is?).

Comment: Not sure, but you do not need `__declspec(dllexport)` for a static library. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: @john in windows you need it. besides, compilation works fine.

Comment: OK, sanity check. The `link` command is not used to create static libraries (only DLLs and executables). You need the `lib` command.

Comment: @canonier No, you are wrong about that. It's needed for DLLs not static libraries.

Comment: @canonier Maybe that is your confusion, you are really trying to build a DLL?

Comment: @BoP The linker itself creates that file.

Comment: @john I don't want to argue on that. That's not the point here. Using VS compilation everything works fine. So it's not the source code issue.

Comment: @canonier OK, but if you want to build a static library you need the `lib` command not the `link` command

Comment: @john I'm trying to build a library.lib. Not a library.dll.

Comment: @canonier library.lib is a static library, for that you need the lib command

Comment: @canonier See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/overview-of-lib?view=msvc-170, although this calls them 'standard libraries', everyone but MS calls them 'static libraries'.

Comment: @canonier Although `__declspec(dllexport)` would normally be used for a DLL, so I think you are a bit confused about what you want.

Comment: @john testing lib tool, looks promising...

Comment: @john Tested on my original source code. It worked. So it looks that I was using wrong tool. Thanks john. Now I have issues with building the main project, which uses those libraries (*.lib). But this is another topic. I'll try to solve it by myself.

Comment: I don't know how to mark John's comment as an answer. So I closed that question by myself. Is it ok?

Comment: @canonier Fine by me, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using wrong tool. I was supposed to use **lib.exe** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/overview-of-lib?view=msvc-170) instead of **link.exe**.

See the comments of **John**.

Thanks a lot **John**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).